# Search input on every page. Django

Tags: python, django, search

I have a web site on Django.
I want to create a search input on every page.
In some "base.html" I write new  for this search input.

In views.py I add something like:

```
def main(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        search_string = request.POST['search_string']
        result = search(search_string)
        return direct_to_template(request, 'found_page.html', {'result': result})`
```

But I want it on EVERY page.

So, I create new function "search_function(request)" and add it to EVERY def in views.py.
Or I can create a decorator and write it before EVERY def in views.py.

I don't want to do it EVERY time I add new def.
But I don't know how.
Need your help

Comment: Perhaps you can work in your issue with [middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/?from=olddocs)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So this is what I think you want to do: display a search input form on every page (whichever applicable), and use only one views to handle the search.

1. create one view that handles search
2. create a html page that has the `<form>` element of the search whose action goes to your views done in the previous step
3. include or extend it in your base.html

What I don't get is, do you need the search happen to be the search on the local page?  (for example, search within this forum)

To get the query you can just supply the query by `request.GET['q']` or `request.POST['q']` or similar.

```
def search(request):
  if 'q' in request.GET and request.GET['q']:
     // do something
```

Unless your search (query) changes the state of the query result in the database, you don't want to use `POST`. Use `GET` instead.

Comment: Thanks. 'action' in <form>. I absolutely forgot about it.

Comment: @user1185123 No problem. Use `GET` instead of `POST`. It's a waste to create new resource when you are querying (searching). Hope this helps!

Comment: resources? i don't understand why get is better then post in this case

Comment: The really old convention is that if your search doesn't modify the data you are retrieving (for example, simply query how many bookmarks does a user has), use GET. If your query modifies something (ex: query bookmarks named 'harry potter' and saves the list of results to user's bookmark list), then use POST. It's subtle thing. It doesn't matter in many cases, but it's a good practice. If you prefer with `POST` it's fine :) This convention is used by people in the industry. There is also `PUT` which is similar to `POST`, modifies the data, but does not create resource.

Comment: thank you. Didn't know about this. Will use GET now more often)

Answer (score 0):

Set the action of the form to go to a different search view and let that one function take care of the search processing.  You can have a dedicated search page and do the exact same thing for checking if the form is 'POST' or 'GET'.  'POST' is a search already done from any other previous page.